# Getting a "Could not load file or assembly" although it should be there

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm working on an Azure Function that uses a couple of nuget packages to decode Json web tokens.

I've referenced System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions in the project.json and it compiles fine.

I'm able to use classes and methods from System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt but it appears that Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions cannot see the assembly.

```
"One or more errors occurred. Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=4.0.20622.1351, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

I double checked the dependencies from the nuget package source and in Kudu to ensure they are present.

I'm a bit stuck as to what to investigate next!

Cheers,

Jordan.

Comment: Hrm... I came back later and it's working now.

Nothing of note changed... I'm double checking I've not altered something that made it work but for now it appears to be black magic :/

Comment: Reviewing unanswered questions - everything work out for you?

Comment: Hi Chris - thanks for following up. It did start working, but apparently of it's own accord - I feel that some cache or similar was causing issues.

Comment: We've seen some issues with assemblies being in place but not getting pulled into the runtime until the host restarts. We'll be improving that whole pipeline over the next month or so.

Comment: in future use fuslogvw to see the full details of the failed load